# Custom annotation move animation IOS Swift Like Ola Uber App MapKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

This is repost.
I want to move custom annotation with animation like Ola uber car with 
rotation.

Please only provide solution in **SWIFT**

**Here is que link**

[move animation with custom annotation IOS Swift Like Ola Uber App MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989642/move-animation-with-custom-annotation-ios-swift-like-ola-uber-app-mapkit)

I only know swift

Comment: I'm not good in Objective C. Please provide any swift link

Comment: This is my post  ;)  with no Solution :) @Kosuke Ogawa

Comment: This is too late to write comment, but it may helps you in future. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650366/move-the-annotation-on-map-like-uber-ios-application